# How to hide the whole empty columns in php/html

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

just would like to hide the whole empty columns in my table.

the code for table is below:

```
   <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" id="weatherTable">

 <tr>
<th align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>DISPLAYED REPORTS AVERAGES:</strong></th>
<td align="center" valign=bottom><font size="4"><b><strong>--</strong></b></font></td>
<td align="center" valign=bottom><font size="4"><b><?php echo $row["air_temp"]; ?></b></font></td>
<td align="center" valign=bottom><font size="4"><?php echo $row["sea_temp"]; ?></font></td>
</tr>

 <tr>
<th align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Station (ID)</strong></td>
<th align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Time<br>(UTC)</strong></td>
<th align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Air Temp<br>(&deg;C)</strong></td>
<th align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Sea Temp<br>(&deg;C)</strong></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>

 if (($sth-> rowCount())>0) {

foreach (($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) as $col) {
?>

<tr>
<td align="right" valign=top><?php echo $col["name"] . " (" . $col["dim_stationID"] . ")"; ?></td>
<td align="center" valign=top><?php $d = $col["date_time"]; $t = explode(" ",$d); $s = explode (":",$t[1]); echo "".$s[0]."".$s[1].""; ?> </td>
<td align="center" valign=top><?php echo $col["air_temp"]; ?></td>
<td align="center" valign=top><?php echo $col["sea_temp"]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

the data is filled in this 4 columns id each report per row, and i've set the averages value on the top of the table for each column, so now the last column "Sea Temp" are empty, how can i hide that whole column?

PS: i was coding

```
 $('td:empty').each(function(i){
 $(this).hide().parents('weatherTable').find('th:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').hide();
 });
```

but that code is hide every empty field(don't want),  such as there have three rows for different report under the column "Air Temp", and there have one rows contain data in that column, another two rows are empty. logically, this column should not hide due to the whole column is not empty.

Comment: You can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003335/hiding-a-table-column-if-the-containing-cells-are-empty-with-jquery

Comment: what is wrong with just `&nbsp;` to leave the `<td>` empty?

Comment: Check [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003335/hiding-a-table-column-if-the-containing-cells-are-empty-with-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered in [Hiding a table column if the containing cells are empty with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003335/hiding-a-table-column-if-the-containing-cells-are-empty-with-jquery) (answered by maclema), you could use something like this:

```
var numCols = $("th", table).length;
for ( var i=1; i<=numCols; i++ ) {
    var empty = true;
    //grab all the <td>'s of the column at i
    $("td:nth-child(" + i + ")", table).each(function(index) {
        //check if the td is not empty
        if ( $(this).text() != "" ) {
            empty = false;
            return false; //break out of each() early
        }
    });
    if ( empty ) {
        $("td:nth-child(" + i + ")", table).hide(); //hide <td>'s
        $("th:nth-child(" + i + ")", table).hide(); //hide header <th>
    }
}
```

Comment: I was writing exactly the same logic, great approach **lpg**

Answer (score -1):

Try this and you are done

```
function hideEmptyCols(table) {
    var rows = $("tr", table).length-1;
    var numCols = $("th", table).length;
    for ( var i=1; i<=numCols; i++ ) {
        if ( $("span:empty", $("td:nth-child(" + i + ")", table)).length == rows ) {
            $("td:nth-child(" + i + ")", table).hide();
            $("th:nth-child(" + i + ")", table).hide();        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could have atleast credited macloma over at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9003509/6868670 since you plain copied his code and removed the comments from it

Comment: @KevinF. That was a long time ago post and i didn't searched Just replied to the question