# Hide a column if its all fields are null in bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) in my Angularjs application. We can hide a column by setting its visible property false but now I have to hide a column if all fields of that column are coming null. So can anyone please suggest me how to do it?

Code JS File:

```
$scope.mediaTableControl = {
  options: {
    data: $scope.medias,
  },
  columns: [
    {
      field: 'DisplayId',
      title: 'Media Id',
      align: 'center',
      valign: 'bottom',
      sortable: true,
      formatter: mediaIdFormatter
    },
    {
      field: 'Created',
      title: 'Date Received',
      align: 'center',
      valign: 'middle',
      formatter: dateFormatter,
      sortable: true
    }
  ]
};
```

HTML file Code:

```
<table bs-table-control="datasetTableControl" id="datasetTable"></table>
```

Comment: You have to write custom code for it. Use angular filter to find that field value is not null. Then check the filtered array size is not zero. If it is zero set the column hide or remove it from columns array. Try your own first if not success update this question with your code which you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding a table column if the containing cells are empty with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003335/hiding-a-table-column-if-the-containing-cells-are-empty-with-jquery)

Comment: I would not use the bootstrap table as it's controlled with jQuery, and mixing Angularjs and jQuery is generally a bad practice. I would go with [smart table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/), which plays well together with Angular.